# SAP Business One DI API for ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, sap-business-one-di-api

I developed one console application using DI API(x64). Now I am trying to develop a web application using the same code but getting the following error in the very first line

```
SAPbobsCOM.Company sboCompany = new SAPbobsCOM.Company(); //in this line
```

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with `CLSID {632F4591-AA62-4219-8FB6-22BCF5F60090}` failed due to the following error:

> 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I have tried changing `Platform target` (`x84, any, x64`) but no luck. I also have `Enabled 32-Bit Applications on IIS`.

I am using Visual studio 2017 community version and Windows 10(x64).

I have no idea why I am getting this error as its perfectly working for my console application. I have seen some are suggesting to use `DI Server for web application` but I am wondering if its possible to use DI API as I won't have much traffic.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try using DI API 32 bit?

Comment: I din not try with that as DI API 64 bit perfectly working for console application on the same local PC.

Comment: Hi Kinyanjui, after installing 32 bit DI API this problem solved but I am getting another error. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183080/di-api-with-asp-net-web-application-error-failed-to-get-license-server-address
Any idea why this is happening?